# alternative for tool tip and horizontal scroll for javascript drop down list

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, tooltip

As we know IE SELECTdrop down list has limitations on tool tip on individual option items and also horizontal scroll bar.
Can any one please tell any other alternative to show the tool tip using javascript or has any one implemented drop down list using div which has all the functionalites of drop down list.

Thanks,
Nags

Answer (score 1):

[Sexy Combo demo page](http://phone.witamean.net/sexy-combo/examples/index.html)

[jquery combobox demo](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/samples/example.htm)